# how to calculate value differences between two neighboring fields

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to calculate distances between two neighboring fields. My input file is like below.

> 1 11160 11533 11556 11731 11822 11870 12149 12411 12461 12686 12829 13315 13420 ....

In the output, I want to keep the first field, and the following field would be the value differences between the current field and the next field, `$2=$3-$2`, `$3=$4-$3` ...

A complete output will be like:

> 1 373  23  175 91  48  279 262 50  225 143 486 105...

How can I do this?

In my code, each value is printed as a new line also the numbers are reversely printed.

```
BEGIN {FS=" "}
{
        out[1]=$1
        for (i=2;i<=NF-1;i++) 
                out[i]=$(i+1)-$i
}
END{
        for (i in out)
               print out[i]
}
```

Here is current output

> 373
>   23
>   175
>   91
>   48
>   279
>   262
>   50
>   225
>   143
>   486
>   105
>   1

Comment: Good first Q with input data, expected output and (gasp!) some actual code, but please edit  your Q to include the current output from your sample data. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding code suggested by anubhava sir too in comment section.

```
awk '{s=$1; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) s = s OFS $(i+1) - $i; print s}' Input_file
```

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{printf $1 OFS;for(i=2;i<NF;i++){printf("%d%s",$(i+1)-$i,i==(NF-1)?ORS:OFS)}}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 373 23 175 91 48 279 262 50 225 143 486 105
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here.

```
awk '
{
  printf $1 OFS                                 ##Printing first field and OFS(whose value is space by default).
  for(i=2;i<NF;i++){                            ##Starting for loop from value of 2 to till NF-1 value where NF is number of field in current line.
    printf("%d%s",$(i+1)-$i,i==(NF-1)?ORS:OFS)  ##Printing diffrence of next field and current field and checking condition for 2nd print if i==NF-1 then new line else print space for that line.
  }                                             ##Closing for loop block here.
}
' Input_file                                    ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: `awk '{s=$1; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) s = s OFS $(i+1) - $i; print s}' file` might be shorter.

Comment: @anubhava, sure sir added this nice solution too now, thanks for letting know.

Comment: I tried, this works, is there any way to expand this code to multiple lines?

Comment: @theronless, this should work for all the lines of a Input_file when you run it for a Input_file which has more than 1 line in it.

Comment: @anubhava could this be memory intensive if running on big files?

Comment: Not much memory impact as this command is not storing anything beyond a record.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{printf("%d",$1); for (i=2;i<NF;i++) printf(" %d",$(i+1)-$i)}' file
```

Output:

```
1 373 23 175 91 48 279 262 50 225 143 486 105
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'NR!=2{printf "%s ", $0-p} {p=$0}' file

1 373 23 175 91 48 279 262 50 225 143 486 105
```

you may want to add a final `\n`.

Your specification corresponds to displaying all pairwise diffs expect second one that's why there is `NR!=2` code.  First field is compared to 0, so stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it! Just need to change the output from `print out[i]` to:

```
printf out[i] " "
```

The `printf` will not append a newline after each iteration, and instead you tack on a space.

The output I recieved from the above adjustment turned into:

> ```
> 1 373 23 175 91 48 279 262 50 225 143 486 105
> ```

As far as the "numbers not making sense", they are as you are expecting, a difference between the consecutive numbers.

Comment: Thanks, this works, the only thing is somehow the array was printed in a descending order ($1 was positioned at last), that makes me think they were wrong.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you, so it may guide others if they stumble across a similar issue. :)